# Solidify modifier issue for increasing thickness

Tags: modifiers

I am creating 3D model of iPhone Case.

I have created it. But now I want to increase thickness of it. I tried using solidify modifier. But it is not giving result as I want.

See below is the image with no thickness.
[image]

After using solidify modifier it is not applying properly on **camera cut**.
[image]

Please anyone tell me to how to do this.

Comment: add a edge split modifier below the solidfy modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you can check:

1. Your topology of the case: make sure it has less or no triangles and has a smooth flow.
2. Try adding an edge split modifier.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to reapply the normals of the faces.

Comment: Thanks @crz, I have applied edge split modifier after solidify modifier and it solved my problem :)